# How to avoid duplicate validation in web tier and service tier?

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc

If I have a web app, say I'm using Spring MVC, and I add validation in my forms and controllers. I might also have validation in my service tier in case clients access my app in some other manner (through a REST service, etc). In this case I'm likely to have validation logic/code in multiple places.

Is there a suggested approach to keep the validation portion DRY?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lots of people will tell you how to do this.  I'm going to answer with why you might not want to.

In an N-tier system, the tiers all operate semi-autonomously.  But that doesn't mean they can - or should - rely on another tier to guarantee data consistency and validity.

There are two major reasons.  First, an N-tier system is expandable.  For example, in a web system a new front end might take advantage of an existing web tier to do something never thought of in the original design.  So you are design proofing your system by allowing for something new to come at some middle point in the tiers.

Second, validation is often most effective the closer it is to the user.  If I'm in a browser based solution and I type in the wrong password in a double-enter validation field, I would like the browser to point that out immediately.  Waiting for the round trip takes time and frustrate the user.

Now take that same example and move it to the logic tier.  The logic tier, not exactly sure who is sending it data, wants to make certain that it is receiving two matching passwords.  So it also checks, and returns an error if they don't match.  This protects the data from bad changes.

It's just a philosophy, but it has worked well for me in the past.

Comment: You are right that validation is more effective closer to the user, but usually it is possible to describe your validation constraints in the Domain Model which is also used in the Service Layer. E.g. the service layer returns an error object and the web layer is responsible for translating it and another service layer user will process it the way they need to.

Comment: This seems to make the most sense. I was asking the question b/c I'm attending the "Developing Rich Web Applications with Spring" training and during the Spring MVC discussion they show how to do validation. A question was asked about the potential duplication of validation logic by having some of it in the controller/form area and in the service area.

Comment: Although the code should ideally be run in both tiers, that isn't a good case for actually duplicating code (say in two different languages), especially if the concern is theoretical ("design proofing"), since when the validation logic changes (and it always does in useful systems) it will have to be fixed correctly in two (or more!) different places. Sometimes you have no choice, but certainly not as a "future-proofing" exercise.

Comment: @Daff By permitting Domain Models or Value Objects to perform validation, how do you map the validation error back to the specific erroneous field that came through the controller?

Comment: I agree, verification can be done in multiple locations.  The point i was trying to make, however, is that verification that is done beyond the direct contact point is inherently suspect.  It's possible for any in-between tier to fake/store/falsify verification information.  So the only TRUE verification is done from each tier to the next directly connected tier.

Answer (score 2):

It would probably be worth having a look at JSR-303 bean validation. If you use the same JavaBeans for the different interfaces you can avoid duplicate validation logic.

The Hibernate implementation provides the best reference documentation:

http://hibernate.org/subprojects/validator

And the Spring reference docs tell you how to integrate it.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-beanvalidation-overview

Answer (score 2):

I would propose that these are different kinds of validation.

Client/controller validation checks to make sure that required values are present, formats are obeyed, etc.

Binding HTTP request parameters into objects to be passed to the service layer is the exclusive responsibility of the controller.

The service tier will perform the same validations as the client side, but also throw in "business validations" that pertain to the use case.  The controller can't know those.

One way to avoid duplication is to execute the same JavaScript functions on the client and server sides.  The server side uses the JavaScript engine to execute the client validations plus the additional ones that pertain to business validation.

Answer (score 0):

Spring uses the [validator](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/validation.html) interface That is one way. I don't know of a reason why you can't use that in the service tier as well. Alternatively, you could use AOP and define pointcuts as needed in any tier.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, business/functional level validation should always go in the service-tier. If you say that you are duplicating validations that were done on your MVC layer is duplicated at service-layer that sounds alarming. For example, on view you may validate things like phone number format, credit card format etc. You must not duplicate these in your service tier.

At the same time you may have to duplicate validations such as "null" checks and those are OK from a design point of view.